# Constructing Epsilon-closures

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I am recently learning about automaton and I was confused at an exercise that was given to me.

In the lecture, we were given this exercise:
Given a FA with transitions 
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    &      a       &      b      & \epsilon \\ \hline
q_1 & \varnothing  & \varnothing & \{q_2\} \\
q_2 & \{q_3, q_4\} & \varnothing & \varnothing \\
q_3 & \varnothing  & \{q_4\}     & \{q_2\} \\
q_4 & \{q_5\}      & \varnothing & \{q_3,q_5\} \\
q_5 & \varnothing  & \varnothing & \varnothing
\end{array}$$
With $E(\{q_1\}) = \{q_1, q_2\},E(\{q_2\}) = \{q_2\},E(\{q_3\}) = \{q_2, q_3\},E(\{q_4\}) = \{q_2, q_3,q_4, q_5\},$

how do you construct something as $E(\{q_1, q_3, q_5\}) = \{q_1, q_2, q_3, q_5\}$?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a link to a problem. One of the aims of this site is to provide an archive of questions and answers; a link might not point to a valid location a year or two in the future. I took the liberty of transcribing the contents of the link into LaTeX. To see the markup that produced this, just click on the "edited ..." icon immediately to the left of your name.

Comment: It would be nice to give in the question the definition of
Epsilon-closure. May-be the question would have disappeared with a
pop. Often you get the answer to a question just by stating
definitions. Also, a proper proof depends on the definitions you start
from. So asking without providing definitions may be bad practice, the
precise counterpart of trying to answer without reminding yourself of
the definitions.

Comment: @babou I agree in principle, but I think the $\epsilon$-closure is (as part of the powerset construction) fairly standard.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Check the formal definition of $E$.

Answer (score 3):

If $s_i$ are states in the original FA, then the $\epsilon$-closure, 
$$
E(\{s_1, \dotsc, s_n\})=\bigcup_{i=1}^nE(\{s_i\})
$$
so in your example we'll have
$$\begin{align}
E(\{q_1,q_3,q_5\})&=E(\{q_1\})\cup E(\{q_3\})\cup E(\{q_5\})\\
 &= \{q_1, q_2\}\cup \{q_2, q_3\}\cup\{q_5\}\\
 &= \{q_1, q_2, q_3, q_5\}
\end{align}$$
It's the set of all states reachable from $q_1$ or $q_3$ or $q_5$ by either staying where you are or by following $\epsilon$-moves.