# Question Regarding ECLOSURE in ε-NFAs

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have a small question regarding the **ECLOSURE** of a certain state in an **ε-NFA**.

If we have a **transition** that has both **a** and **ε** transitions, is the **ECLOSURE** affected?

Also is there any rule that in **ECLOSURE** we should include the states that are accessible only from transitions containing **ε**?

Comment: What's the definition of the ε-closure you have? I think the answer is already in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40445/constructing-epsilon-closures

Comment: $\epsilon$-closure simply means: given a set of states $S$, enlarge that set to include *also* all states that are reachable from a state in $S$ via only $\epsilon$-transitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\epsilon$-closure of a state $p$ is the set of all states, including $p$ itself, that are reachable by *only* by a chain of consecutive $\epsilon$-moves. Transitions on other inputs are not considered when computing $\epsilon$-closure$(p)$. They come in to play in the next step, when you compute the transition function for the equivalent NFA without $\epsilon$-moves.